# How to find a specific point on image opencv/python

Tags: python, opencv, yolov8

I used OpenCV and `yolov8` to detect instance segment with webcam. Currently, I'm working on detect and find the specific point from detect object through webcam. I have custom data set best.pt files to detect instance segmentation.

As you can see side view image below easily I can find the two points which is blue and red dot. For red dot I used biggest y value from segments and for blue dot smallest x value from segments.

side view:

[image: side view]

But I can't find the blue dot from front view image. Is there any way to find the specific point from image?

front view:

[image: front view]

Final goal is find the blue dot from detected objects through webcam.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you are able to find the red dot's position in the second image, camera remains at the same distance from the table and the object has negligible thickness,
I think the following should work.

1. Find the red dot's position in the second image. Let's call it red_image_2.
2. Find `blue_image_1[y] - red_image_1[y]`. Let's call this `dist_from_bottom`
3. Blue dot's position in image 2 is `red_image_2[y] - dist_from_bottom`